# Strapi route returns 404

Tags: node.js, routes, strapi, koa

I have setup a directory under src/api folder for my singleType data with schema like this:

```
{
  "kind": "singleType",
  "name": "default_currency",
  "collectionName": "default-currencies",
  "info": {
    "singularName": "default-currency",
    "pluralName": "default-currencies",
    "displayName": "DefaultCurrency",
    "description": "Set default conversion currency"
  },
  "options": {
    "draftAndPublish": true
  },
  "pluginOptions": {},
  "attributes": {
    "currencyCode": {
      "type": "string",
      "required": true,
      "default": "USDT"
    },
    "currencyName": {
      "type": "string",
      "required": true,
      "default": "Tether"
    }
  }
}
```

I can see the desired result in content-manager page in admin, however my route "default-currency" is not present when checking `routes:list`.
I can assure that controller, services and routes are set the way it was supposed to be set. (I copy pasted it from the docs).

Accessing an endpoint from postman of course gives me 404.
Saving and publishing the data in admin is already had been tried.

Comment: have you enabled the route from admin settings

Comment: @mainak if you are talking about routes under setttings->roles-> (routes permission) then no, because i cant see my new routes there

Comment: there are only the routes that come out of the box

Comment: I will suggest you do it from beginning and before that check how to add a custom route in strapi based on your strapi version v4 or v3

Comment: @mainak yeah that is what i already did